# Хэширование коммита

Tags: git

Как хэшируется коммит? Для хэширования коммита используется название этого коммита или может дата?

Comment: Он считается по хэшу объекта commit, который содержит в себе всю информацию о коммите — дата, автор, комментарий, подпись и т.п. Плюс к этому он содержит хэш объекта tree, а объект tree содержит хэши конкретных файлов, добавленных в репозиторий. Также в коммите содержатся хэши родительских коммитов, так что в сумме получается, что коммит косвенно хэшируется по абсолютно всему содержимому репозитория в текущей ветке, начиная с самого-самого первого коммита

Answer (score 3):

всю информацию, которую содержит объект, можно посмотреть такой командой:

```
$ git cat-file тип-объекта хэш-объекта
```

к примеру, для [объекта типа *commit* с хэшем `3cbc0fb39c84ae0a51a9a88649dccd105bf17d6e`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/3cbc0fb39c84ae0a51a9a88649dccd105bf17d6e):

```
$ git cat-file commit 3cbc0fb39c84ae0a51a9a88649dccd105bf17d6e
tree 71173edd7df0127465dcec352cf76c90cbf1e446
parent fc36b97af05ef74b0889ba49090c2f52f00e0e77
author Harald Anlauf <anlauf@gmx.de> 1593262593 +0200
committer Harald Anlauf <anlauf@gmx.de> 1593262648 +0200

PR fortran/95881 - ICE in resolve_symbol, at fortran/resolve.c:15175

Avoid NULL pointer dereference.

gcc/fortran/
    PR fortran/95881
    * resolve.c (resolve_symbol): Avoid NULL pointer dereference.
```

здесь:

- `tree хэш` — хэш-сумма объекта типа *tree*
- `parent хэш` — хэш-сумма объекта типа *commit*, «родителя» данного коммита
- `author ...`, `committer ...` — в пояснениях не нуждается. обратите внимание: в этих полях присутствует в том числе и время (указанное соответственно автором и коммитером: это могут быть разные лица)
- дальше текст сообщения, прикреплённого к коммиту

это пример самый простейший, только с основной, «базовой» информацией. в более «навороченных» коммитах может присутствовать и другая информация: и описание метки (*tag*), и подписи, и дополнительные «родительские» коммиты (для коммита слияния) и проч.

---

хэш (sha1-сумма) высчитывается от такой информации:

```
тип-объекта длина-объекта\0содержимое-объекта
```

для приведённого выше примера можно пересчитать хэш таким вот образом:

```
$ (printf "commit %s\0" $(git cat-file commit 3cbc0fb39 | wc -c); git cat-file commit 3cbc0fb39) | sha1sum 
3cbc0fb39c84ae0a51a9a88649dccd105bf17d6e  -
```

хэш получился идентичный.

Answer (score 1):

В хэш записывается [много-много всяких параметров](https://gist.github.com/masak/2415865)

- автор
- кто закоммитил
- хэш родительского коммита (получается такой себе блокчейн - нельзя без перетряхивания всей репы подменить один файл)
- хэш от дерева данного коммита, который в свою очередь составлен из хешей всех блобов и поддеревьев
- хэш от текста описания коммита