# Как узнать какой будет hash моего commit'a?

Tags: git, github

Интересен вопрос в том, при помощи какой команды я могу узнать какой будет hash моего коммита при `git push` на github.

Comment: Попробуйте `git branch -rv` после отправки. Но, конечно, git push не меняет хеш коммита.

Comment: есть ответ на заголовок вопроса: [хэш можно и самостоятельно посчитать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1146449/178576)

Answer (score 4):

`git push` не создает новых комитов. Эта команда передает уже созданные локально комиты и добавляет их в remote репозиторий.

Посмотреть комиты и их идентификаторы в текущем бранче (а именно от передается) можно командой `git log`.